# NHibernate: mapping user type object to a separate table

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

Let's start with this mapping:

```
<component name="Location">
  ...
  <property name="Settings" type="JsonUserType,...">
    <column name="LocationSettingsType" />
    <column name="LocationSettingsData" />
  </property>
</component>
```

This maps to

```
TABLE Primary (
    ...
    LocationSettingsType,
    LocationSettingsData
    ...
)
```

and

```
class Location {
    ...
    object Settings { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I want to extract settings into a separate table (because they are seldom here).
So I get

```
TABLE Primary (
    ...
    LocationSettingsId,
    ...
)

TABLE Settings (
    Id,
    Type,
    Data
)
```

**Can I keep my C# classes the same?**

**Update:** This is not a many-to-one relationship. As before, each location has zero or one settings, and each settings belong to at most one location.

Comment: Honestly, I'm still confused as to what you're going for here...if you want to split out part of a entity into a second table, perhaps you want the <join> mapping?

Comment: I wanted to, but <join> is not supported inside the <component>.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the closest thing that exists to this is the `<map>` mapping element; details are explained in [this article](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/06/03/nhibernate-mapping-ndash-ltmapgt.aspx).

Comment: Map requires dictionary, and I do not have a dictionary in my C# model, I opted for JsonUserType instead (because I do not need to process settings on the DB side and I want strong typing in C#).

Answer (score 0):

If you want a one to many relationship on the Primary and Settings tables, you'll have to set a foreign key constraint first. Then you'll use the `bag` property in XML to map your tables. You will have an `entity` for each table.

See also this question on [NHibernate/FluentNHibernate Property Bag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814931/nhibernate-fluentnhibernate-property-bag).

I also recommend you purchase the [NHibernate 2 for Beginners](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1847198902) book. It helped me alot.

Comment: No, as before the table split, it should still be a one to one relationship.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but i had the same issue and looking to a solution I came here.

the `component` element can map several columns to several object models.

the `join` element can map several tables to an object model.

The main problem is that while the `component` cannot map columns from a different table where the model belong, the `join` cannot map the different table columns to a different object model.

The solution I found is to use both to achieve the map column of a different table to several object:

```
<class name="Primary" table="Primary">
    <id name="Id">
        <generator class="identity"/>
    </id>
    <property name="Name" />
    ...
    <join table="Settings">
        <key column="PrimaryId"/>

        <component name="Location">
          ...
          <property name="Settings" type="JsonUserType,...">
            <column name="LocationSettingsType" />
            <column name="LocationSettingsData" />
          </property>
        </component>
    </join>
</class>
```

Reference:

[NHibernate Join mapping element](http://ayende.com/blog/3961/nhibernate-mapping-join)

[NHibernate Component mapping element](http://ayende.com/blog/3937/nhibernate-mapping-component)